# Add actionbarsherlock appcompat v7 to a project

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have a project using actionbarsherlock working properly, but when I add a new Activity eclipse adds appcompat v7 automatically, add the projects doesn't compile anymore and it errors 100s of times saying some resources are already added to project.

Comment: Why do you still want to use ABS in a new project? Google recommends using ABC in new project. The support of ABS will drop over time, so you basically are starting with a legacy.

Comment: @for3st it's not a new project, it's an old BIG project :) So adding ABC is hard

Answer (score 0):

You basically have to create the Java class manually, then create the XML file manually, then declare the `Activity` in your Android manifest. I ran into this issue and was really frustrated why they are forcing this `AppCompat` down our throats whenever we create a new activity